# Is there a way to extract whether an OS is "Linux" from aws ec2 cli?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Looking at the output from `aws ec2 describe-instances` I see an "ImageId = amixxxxx" but I don't see anything that tells me the operating system, whether it is Linux or something else. Is there a way to get this information from `describe-instances`?

`describe-images` provides a "Description" that tells me it's Linux (among other things). But interestingly does not tell me the "Platform", although you can see it if you navigate to the "Images > AMIs" section of the Console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command will display the `Platform` parameter, which is either set to `windows` or is blank:

```
$ aws ec2 describe-instances --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,Platform]' --output text

i-9c9c9b94  None
i-cdb618a2  None
i-3d263640  None
i-bc57c751  windows
i-3eaa31d2  windows
i-294b95c7  None
```

So, a blank/None entry would indicate Linux.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.